# Stack Overflow and DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: support, authentication, technology, dotnetopenauth

I understand that Stack Overflow uses DotNetOpenAuth for login.  Since there are things that work at Stack Overflow but don't work in the demos at DotNetOpenAuth.net, there must be some additional code at Stack Overflow.  For example, you can log into Stack Overflow with email addresses that are not OpenId's such as gmail addresses.

How is this done?  Is the code available?

Comment: This is a close call, but I think the question is phrased SO specific enough that it would probably get better answers on Meta; hence I'm moving it there.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, today we are using DotNetOpenAuth (one of the latest versions), we often upgrade and try to stay ahead with the patches.

There is some minor amount of propriety code in the way we deal with sregs and the like but nothing really ground breaking that could not emulated by other consumers.